# WhatsApp invalid num of params

Tags: whatsapp

What is wrong with the message?
My WhatsApp template has two params: 
lorem ipsum {{1}}, dolor sit amet {{2}}

```
data = {
    'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
    'recipient_type': 'individual',
    'to': f'{mobile}',
    'type': 'template',
    'template': {
        'name': 'inform',
        'language': {
            'code': 'pt_PT',
        },
    },
    'components' : [{
        'type': 'header',
        'parameters': [{
            'type': 'text',
                'text': name,
        },
        {
            'type': 'text',
             'text': msg,
        }]
     }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, your request is invalid, the `components` property should be inside the `template` object,

```
data = {
    'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
    'recipient_type': 'individual',
    'to': f'{mobile}',
    'type': 'template',
    'template': {
        'name': 'inform',
        'language': {
            'code': 'pt_PT',
        },
        'components' : [{
            'type': 'header',
            'parameters': [{
                'type': 'text',
                    'text': name,
            },
            {
                'type': 'text',
                 'text': msg,
            }]
        }]
    }    
}
```

You can refer to the documentation: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#interactive